# What will happen if border-box is applied on an image in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I have encountered an issue with Firefox that if border-box is applied to an image, a gap is created on the right side.

```
<div id="sl">
  <img class="der" src="https://www.google.com/logos/2012/francois_truffaut-2012-hp.jpg"/>
</div>
```

```
#sl
{
  background-color: #ff0;
  display: inline-block; 
}

body
{
  background-color: #f00;
}

.der
{
  height: 60px;   
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #00f;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Firefox only: http://jsfiddle.net/r2GLU/

The question is why is this behavior? I guess that `border-box` shouldn't have been applied on image in the first place, but I don't think that it is forbidden either and Firefox is the only one who has problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've encountered a bug in Firefox. The original, un-resized image is 163px high by 421px long.

Now, looking at the computed styles in Firebug, the `img` has these values (I've added comments showing how they were computed):

```
height: 58px;      /* img-height = box-height - box-border = 60 - 2 = 58 */
width: 149.8px;    /* img-width = img-height * aspect-ratio = 58 * (421 / 163) = 149.8 */
```

And the div has these values:

```
height: 60px;      /* div-height = img-height + box-border = 58 + 2 = 60 */
width: 156.967px;  /* div-width = div-height * aspect-ratio + box-border = 60 * (421 / 163) + 2 = 156.967 */
```

The bug is that last computation. It should have been:

```
width: 151.8px;  /* div-width = img-height * aspect-ratio + box-border = 58 * (421 / 163) + 2 = 151.8 */
```

Comment: The encounter with this bug almost killed me. It took hours to disassemble a pile of CSS.

Comment: I searched the bugzilla database and couldn't find anything about this, but it's not the easiest thing to search for. I'd submit the bug myself, but I don't have a bugzilla account, and don't really care to get one. If someone else has a bugzilla account and wants to post it, that might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue to be caused because of not specifying the *width*;

```
.der
{
    width:421px;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid #00f;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Still this is an obvious bug.

Comment: Yeah, a bug. I was in the middle of posting an answer explaining the exact location of the bug when you posted this. Just posted it.